# Laravel Models Poperty of non-object

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, models, relationships

I have a People table

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `job_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `profile_pic` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `departments` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=95 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

An a departments table

```
CREATE TABLE `departments` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `people_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `department_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

- One person can be in many departments
- In the departments table the foreign_key is people_id

In my people model

```
public function departments()
    {
 return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Departments', 'id', 'people_id');

    }
```

and finally I try and return some results

```
 return $people::find(1)->departments;
```

I get the error,

```
**ErrorException in web.php line 129:
Trying to get property of non-object**
```

Forgive me if this is a stupid error, I have used laravel for a while but never set up models with relationships before.

Comment: Are you sure your model class is called Departaments? Normally it's singular. So it would be: `$this->hasMany('App\Models\Department')`;

Comment: No, it is departments

Comment: Try: `return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Departments', 'people_id', 'id');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this Piece of code:-

```
Get All records
$people = People::with('departments')->get();
$people = json_decode(json_encode($people),true) //Convert in to array
echo "<pre>"; print_r($people); die; //print it

Get 1 record
$people = People::with('departments')->first();
$people = json_decode(json_encode($people),true) //Convert in to array
echo "<pre>"; print_r($people); die; //print it
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

So in the end it was a stupid issue.

```
$people::find(1)->departments;
```

Find takes an id but the id of 1 did not exist.